# How to split folders to 3 datasets with ImageDataGenerator?

Tags: python, keras, imagedatagenerator

validation_split parameter is able to allow ImageDataGenerator to split the data sets reading from the folder into 2 different disjoint sets. Is there any way to create 3 sets - of training, validation, and evaluation datasets using it?

I am thinking about splitting the dataset into 2 datasets, then splitting the 2nd dataset into another 2 datasets

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(validation_split=0.5, rescale=1./255)

train_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    TRAIN_DIR, 
    subset='training'
)

val_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    TRAIN_DIR,
    subset='validation'
)
```

Here I am thinking about splitting the validation dataset into 2 sets using val_generator. One for validation and the other for evaluation? How should I do it?

Comment: No, this way will create a different test set for each time you run the code while the test must be identical for every evaluation. You should split your data into 2 folders (or even 1 more for validation as well) for training and testing, then use the above code to split images in the train folder into training and testing parts.

Comment: sklearn's train_test_split() might serve you better here

Comment: Hi, Since you are using flow_from_directory it might not be so viable to do so. Instead you can first split your data into three subfolders of train, validation and test and then can use flow_from_directorty or alternatively follow this tutorial i wrote some time ago 
https://snawarhussain.com/blog/tensorflow/DataLoading-in-TensorFlow-2/

Answer (score 2):

I like working with the `flow_from_dataframe()` method of `ImageDataGenerator`, where I interact with a simple Pandas DataFrame (perhaps containig other features), not with the directory. But you can easily change my code if you insist on `flow_from_directory()`.

So this is my go-to function, e.g. for a regression task, where we try to predict a continuous `y`:

```py
def get_generators(train_samp, test_samp, validation_split = 0.1):
    train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(validation_split=validation_split, rescale = 1. / 255)
    test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1. / 255)
    
    train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
        dataframe = images_df[images_df.index.isin(train_samp)],
        directory = images_dir,
        x_col = 'img_file',
        y_col = 'y',
        target_size = (IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH),
        class_mode = 'raw',
        batch_size = batch_size,
        shuffle = True,
        subset = 'training',
        validate_filenames = False
    )
    valid_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
        dataframe = images_df[images_df.index.isin(train_samp)],
        directory = images_dir,
        x_col = 'img_file',
        y_col = 'y',
        target_size = (IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH),
        class_mode = 'raw',
        batch_size = batch_size,
        shuffle = False,
        subset = 'validation',
        validate_filenames = False
    )

    test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
        dataframe = images_df[images_df.index.isin(test_samp)],
        directory = images_dir,
        x_col = 'img_file',
        y_col = 'y',
        target_size = (IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH),
        class_mode = 'raw',
        batch_size = batch_size,
        shuffle = False,
        validate_filenames = False
    )
    return train_generator, valid_generator, test_generator
```

Things to notice:

- I use two generators
- The input to the function are the train/test indices (such as received from Sklearn's `train_test_split`) which are used to filter the DataFrame index.
- The function also take a `validation_split` parameter for the training generator
- `images_df` is a DataFrame somewhere in global memory with proper columns like `img_file` and `y`.
- No need to `shuffle` validation and test generators

This can be further generalized for multiple outputs, classification, what have you.

Answer (score 0):

I mostly have been splitting data in 80/10/10 for training, validation and test respectivelly.

When working with keras I favor the [`tf.data` API](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset) as it provides a good abstraction for complex input pipelines

It does not provide a simple `tf.data.DataSet.split` functionality though

I have this function (that I found from someone's code and my source is missing) which I consistently use

```
def get_dataset_partitions_tf(ds: tf.data.Dataset, ds_size, train_split=0.8, val_split=0.1, test_split=0.1, shuffle=True, shuffle_size=10000):
    assert (train_split + test_split + val_split) == 1

    if shuffle:
    # Specify seed to always have the same split distribution between runs
        ds = ds.shuffle(shuffle_size, seed=12)

    train_size = int(train_split * ds_size)
    val_size = int(val_split * ds_size)

    train_ds = ds.take(train_size)    
    val_ds = ds.skip(train_size).take(val_size)
    test_ds = ds.skip(train_size).skip(val_size)

    return train_ds, val_ds, test_ds
```

Firstly read your data set, and get its size(with [cardianlity method](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#cardinality)), then pass it into the function and you're good to go!

This function can be given a flag to shuffle the original dataset before creating the splits, this is useful to have more realistic validation and test metrics.

The seed for shuffling is fixed so that we can run the same function and the splits remain the same, which we want for consistent results.